# Dailymotion API return very old cached version

Tags: caching, dailymotion-api

My application load regulary the number of viewers watching a livestream on dailymotion.

I use the dailymotion API with the field "audience" to do that.

But the server is sending to me a really really old cached version of the precious JSON file.

For example, a streamer is live since 2 hours, but the API is sending this to me :

```
curl https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x25eyo8?fields=audience
{"audience":0}
```

If i add another field just a few seconds later, just to see :

```
curl https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x25eyo8?fields=audience,onair
{"audience":1177, onair: true}
```

And if I re-send the first request

```
curl https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x25eyo8?fields=audience
{"audience":0}
```

More interesting, the headers sent by the server show this :

```
curl -I https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x25eyo8?fields=audience
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: DMS/1.0.42
X-Dm-Api-Object: video
X-DM-BackNode: web-011.adm.dailymotion.com:80
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10, stale-if-error=900
X-Dm-Api-Method: info
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-DM-LB: 195.8.215.130
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-DM-BackNode-Response-Time: 47
Etag: W/"8xO_txIM6arAYYIALcRUgg"
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 20:20:31 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE
X-Dm-Page: fr.rest.rest_api
Via: 1.1 varnish
Fastly-Debug-Digest: 1d9daef237214a02cb79d06c44fdaa26329d5bd16c9afda535f3f9b104438b84
Content-Length: 17
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 01:16:59 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 116
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-fra1225-FRA, cache-lhr6323-LHR
X-Cache: HIT, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 1, 0
Vary: X-DM-EC-Geo-Country, Accept-Encoding
```

Age : 116 with a max-age of 10 ?

And even when i receive an "up to date" version (age < 10), the file still contains 0 viewers whereas the stream is online and 1000+ viewers are watching.

Now there are 2 questions :
Why this happens ? 
Can I force a non-cached version ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

It looks like it's the same problem when you watch a stream on http://games.dailymotion.com/. For all channels, numbers of viewers are correct inside the player but for some ones, the number displayed under it is not (most of the time, it indicate 0)
[Example of wrong number of viewers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXIdT.jpg)

Comment: this looks like a bug, we're checking. thanks for the heads-up - Dailymotion Team

Comment: this issue has been solved mid-december but my answer below has been deleted by moderation.

Comment: Effectively, i retrieve correct numbers now. Thank you very much